# postgres, generated columns with array from jsonb

Tags: postgresql

given a table with a `data` column, jsonb type with this content

```
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextualBody",
      "value": "comment",
      "purpose": "commenting"
    },
    {
      "type": "TextualBody",
      "value": "tag1:value",
      "purpose": "tagging"
    }
  ],
```

i'm able to run this query

```
select array(select jsonb_array_elements(data->'body')->>'value' from table where id=1)
```

and obtain this result

```
{comment,tag1:value}
```

i would like to have a generated column `text[]` containing that result.

i tried

```
 tags text[] GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ARRAY(SELECT(jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'body') ->> 'value'))) STORED,
```

with this error

```
ERROR:  cannot use subquery in column generation expression
```

what is the right way to create a such generated column?

Comment: You can create a function, declare it as `IMMUTABLE`, and use that.

Comment: Just curious, why are you storing JSON as text?

Answer (score 0):

thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69159014/postgres-generated-columns-with-array-from-jsonb?noredirect=1#comment122235468_69159014) i solved with this function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tags (data jsonb)
    RETURNS text[]
    AS $CODE$
BEGIN
    RETURN ARRAY (
        SELECT
            jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'body') ->> 'value');
END
$CODE$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
IMMUTABLE;
```

and this stored column

```
tags text[] GENERATED ALWAYS AS (tags (data)) STORED,
```